# Flutter - get rid of shadow on iOS

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dropshadow

I have a Flutter app and I am testing it on iOS. I found that below picture there is shadow (and padding) - picture below. The main problem is padding on the right and on the left.

Does anybody know how to ged rid of it?

Code:

```
return Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
  children: <Widget>[
    roundedImage("assets/images/avatar.png"),
    Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text("XXXXXX",
              style: Theme.of(context)
                  .textTheme
                  .display2
                  .copyWith(fontSize: 20.0)),
          Text("YYYYY",
              style: Theme.of(context)
                  .textTheme
                  .display4
                  .copyWith(fontSize: 14.0)),
        ]),
    Text("ZZZZZ",
        style: Theme.of(context)
            .textTheme
            .display4
            .copyWith(fontSize: 16.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.normal))
  ],
);


 Widget roundedImage(String path) {
    return Material(
     shape: CircleBorder(),
     color: Colors.transparent,
     child: Image.asset('assets/images/xxx.png', width: imageSize, height: 
     imageSize)
 );
```

Picture:
[image: The avatar has a shadow]

Answer (score 1):

you can use Property of **Row** widget To do So if i am not wrong. use **mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,** to remove padding from both sides.

```
Widget roundedImage(String path) {
    return CircleAvatar(
      backgroundImage: AssetImage("images/c1.jpeg"),
      radius: 50.0,
    );
  }
```

Comment: I would like to remove padding from the image (shadow)

Comment: i updated my answer please check it out . if that did not work please add your image.

Answer (score 1):

This wouldn't get rid of the shadow, but a good way to mask it would be to change the `shadowColor` to transparent.

This is how that would look;

```
 Widget roundedImage(String path) {
    return Material(
     shape: CircleBorder(),
     color: Colors.transparent,
     shadowColor: Colors.transparent,
     child: Image.asset('assets/images/xxx.png', width: imageSize, height: 
     imageSize)
 );
```

Comment: Doesn't help me, it's the same. It seems it's default behaviour.

Comment: Sorry Stepan but I'm quite busy at the moment so I may not get the time to look into this. Until then I wish you luck solving this

Comment: Actually problem was from importing files from Sketch.